# Getting error: "could not find stored procedure name" in Nodejs while connecting to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I'm trying to make a post request in Node.js (express), to a SQL Server stored procedure. App is connected to database successfully but it is returning error: could not find stored procedure `PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST`. However, the procedure name is correct, the database is connected.

I'm new to this and I really need this to work. Please help me.

NodeJS code:

```
    await pool.connect();
    const result = await pool.request()
        .input('Name', sql.VarChar(200), name)
        .output('list' sql.VarChar(2000))
        .execute("PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST");
    
    res.send({result});
```

SQL Server tree:

```
- DBName
  - Tables
  - programmability
    - Stored Procedures
       -dbo.PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST
```

**NOTE**: the stored procedure `PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST` code is already working with an ASP.NET app and now I'm trying to call it through a nodejs app.

I tried searching it on Stack Overflow but no post addresses my issue.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server why also tag [[tag:MySQL]]?

Comment: dbo.PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST, it seems you're mixing your schemas, is the schema PKG_ADMINISTRATION or dbo, it can't be both

Comment: if the name is really PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST you need to use quotes perhaps [PKG_ADMINISTRATION.GET_PARTS_LIST], although i would say using dots in the name is a bit weird

Comment: siggemannen you are a life saver brother, it worked by adding brackets "[ ]"

Comment: I really suggest a different name for that proc; don't use names that need delimit identifying. A period (`.`) is a part separator, so putting that in an object's name can be *very* confusing.

Comment: If the above done solve your issue check permissions.

Comment: Thom A, i get it; dots and underScores are bad for procedure's name. (it was another developer who wrote that procedure and I'm not even allowed to change it). Though adding [ ] around procedure name worked very fine.